# What is the recommended way to print a constant string?

Tags: c

Which of the following is recommended?

```
printf("DON>");
```

or

```
const char prompt[] = "DON>";
printf("%s", prompt);
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `printf("DON>")` scans the input for `%` characters and interprets them as format. For example, if you wanted to output a `DON%` prompt, you would have to spell it as `printf("DON%%")`. This is not a problem when using `printf` to display short string literals - such a call is even made in the iconic `hello world` example at the beginning of *The C Programming Language*.

If you are separating the string definition from the printing, as in your second example, the `%s` format is preferred for literal printing. This is both for to avoid the need to quote `%`, and to make the code more maintainable by making it apparent to human readers that the string is being printed literally. You can also use `fputs(prompt, stdout)`, but not `puts(prompt)`, because the latter will also emit an undesired newline.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, if you are not going to use a format specifier anywhere, or your string does not contain a format specifier, the best way is to make use of [`puts()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) function.

If you don't want a newline added at the end of your output, make use of [`fputs()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputs).